# How to align image to the right?

Tags: html, css

At [my website](http://www.businessinstitute.nl/testimonial?lang=nl) I can't get my image aligned to the right.
In my wordpress page it says that it is aligned to the right but in my theme it does not work.
In other themes it is aligned to the right.
Anyone an idea how to css this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very easy mate, the image has a class of alignright. Looks like you dont have any styles for this. add the following to your stylesheet:

`.alignright{float:right}`

You may want to add some margins as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. This did the job!

Comment: @Justmac you're welcome. I've just checked your site and i have a little bit of advice which you may or may not decide to take. Dont add `margin-right`. IMO its better if the image has no margin on the side its floating.

Comment: Absolutely: the infamous IE 'float bug' doubled the specified margin on the side of the float. Not so much a problem nowadays (IE8+), but still worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no `alignright` in your CSS - why not add the following?

```
.alignright
{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS. It looks like you're missing a definition for .alignright

```
.alignright {
    float:right;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}
```

You should probably also add definitions for the other elements mentioned there in order to avoid confusion with your theme in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you could add `float:right;` to the style or css.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float:right` to the `.alignright` class.

Answer (score 0):

you may add several styles to IMG tag:

```
<img style='display:block;float:left;' src="http://www.businessinstitute.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/gert-jan-de-groot.jpg" alt="" title="gert-jan-de-groot" width="120" height="153" class="alignright size-full wp-image-71" />
```

Comment: Avoid using inline style declarations where possible - the element is already marked up with the `alignright` CSS class, so it's best to add some CSS styles for that class.

Comment: agree, it was just for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `float:right` to the  link surrounding the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is your html tag

```
<img src="http://www.businessinstitute.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/gert-jan-de-      groot.jpg" alt="" title="gert-jan-de-groot" width="120" height="153" class="alignright size-full wp-image-71">
```

add this to your css file

```
.wp-image-71
{
float: right;
}
```